# Creating all combinations of a string given character values from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, combinations

```
var = {'A': 'A', 'W': 'AT', 'K': 'GT'}
lst = ['AWK']
```

Given the list and dictionary from above I would like to get the combinations of the string in lst:

```
[A,A,G], [A,A,T],[A,T,G],[A,T,T]
```

These combinations are derived from the string in lst and the variations of that string's individual characters (listed in the dict).

The dictionary is representing the different characters a specific lst character can represent. So a 'W' in lst can actually be an 'A' or 'T'.

As a further example, if lst = ['AW'], then the permutations would be: ['A','A'] and ['A','T'].

I am hoping something like [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) can help me with this.

Comment: Write some code, post it here, and we'll help you from there.

Comment: Given this stick, and this cantaloupe, I want a walrus.

Comment: It seems you've barely explained the problem. That's what @timgeb is getting at. The permutations you are requesting appear quite random.

Comment: If you clarify the question. I will be sure to help you out.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification of what I was trying to do. Hopefully the information in the edits will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `itertools.product` after building the appropriate list of possibilities for each character.  For example:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> var = {'A': 'A', 'W': 'AT', 'K': 'GT'}
>>> word = "AWK"
>>> poss = [var[c] for c in word]
>>> poss
['A', 'AT', 'GT']
>>> list(product(*poss))
[('A', 'A', 'G'), ('A', 'A', 'T'), ('A', 'T', 'G'), ('A', 'T', 'T')]
```

Or, if you want new words instead of tuples:

```
>>> [''.join(p) for p in product(*poss)]
['AAG', 'AAT', 'ATG', 'ATT']
```

(BTW: these aren't permutations.)

Comment: Sorry for the poor description. This is  what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what you are asking, but I would guess this:

```
itertools.product(var.values())
```